# VS2017 .Net Core 2 performance and load test

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core, performance-testing

I am trying to create web performance test and I am not able to refer my .net 2 core projects.

Reason web performance test projects always create in .net4.7.

Is there any better way to approach this for writing Performance & load test for core 2.0 app.

Also when you choose core unit test project, it doesn't give me options to create a load test.

basically, I want to reuse my integration test for my load test. Can anyone help?

Comment: This is a great question, but unfortunately too broad for StackOverflow.

Comment: What tool do you want to use in .net? Maybe there are similar tools for .net core.
Furthermore you could use an external load tool that sends repeated requests. Can't think of any at the top of my head now though, but I guess a quick research would give you some names.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the load testing component , you can find the instructions below

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/quickstart-create-a-load-test-project?view=vs-2017

Comment: SorryI thinks you didn't get my question. Basically I want to create a performance test with .net Core. I have already done those step mentioned in the link where it workes if the project is .Net 4.7